# $t$ is a square $\pmod{2^n}$ if and only if $t\equiv 1 \pmod 8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Show that $t$ is a square $\pmod {2^n} \iff t\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, given that $t$ is odd and $n \ge 3$.

I've tried proving forwards using Hensel's lemma, but got stuck.

Comment: One approach is to show that $x\mapsto x^2$ is $4$-to-$1$ on the units of $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: We haven't covered the theory to do that @Slade

Comment: [Closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66719/11619).

Comment: And [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/475845/11619) is how you do it using Hensel's lemma.

Comment: @TheProblem Who needs theory?  $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$ can be divisible by $2^n$ only under a few specific conditions that can be concluded using basic properties of divisibility.